# How to test deep links in react-navigation

Tags: jestjs, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I configured a deep link in react-navigation using the instructions on https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links#handling-nested-navigators. I have a few nested navigators so the `linking` config that I pass into the `NavigationContainer` is not trivial. So I'd like to write a test for it to prevent future bugs.

Any ideas on how I can write a test for it in Jest so that a given deep link goes to the screen that I wish?

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of options:

- Mock [`Linking`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking) module and render your app, you should have correct pages rendered based on the returned link from `getInitialURL`
- Import the [`getStateFromPath`](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/5b13f818f3c701ce33c2a30f5dd96763069556e4/packages/core/src/getStateFromPath.tsx#L50) function and pass the path and a config and check the returned path

I know you asked for tests, but the linking config is type-checked if you specify a global [`RootParamList`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#specifying-default-types-for-usenavigation-link-ref-etc) - which should already help with having correct nesting without the need for tests.